# Python script to move files to either a train dir or test dir

Tags: python, unix, filehandle

I am the moment making a python script capable of diving my data into either a train dir or test dir.  I provide the script with an ratio, which says what the ratio between train/test should be, an according to that should files randomly be moved either to train or test.

ex. if the ratio = 0.5 then would half of my dataset be in train and the other half in test.

other ex. if the ratio = 0.25 then would 75% dataset be in train and the rest in test.

But the division seem to wrong everytime.. I am trying to seperate 84 files/dirs and can't seem to hit the golden 42/42 seperation.. Any suggesting what could i do differently?

Here is the code:

```
import sys
import os
import shutil
import numpy
import random 


src = sys.argv[1]
destination_data = sys.argv[2]

src_abs = os.path.abspath(src)
destination_data_abs = os.path.abspath(destination_data)

src_files = os.listdir(src_abs)


def copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None, split=0.5):
    for item in os.listdir(src):
        s = os.path.join(src, item)
        d = os.path.join(dst, item)
        d_test = os.path.join(dst, 'test', item)
        d_train = os.path.join(dst, 'train', item)

        print d_test
        print d_train
        minmax=0.0, 1.0
        rand = random.uniform(*minmax)
        print rand
        if rand > split:
            # Inserted into train
            if os.path.isdir(s):
                shutil.copytree(s, d_train, symlinks, ignore)
                print "Copytree used! - TRAIN"
            else:
                shutil.copy2(s, d_train)
                print "Copy 2 used! - TRAIN"
        else:
            # Inserted into test
            if os.path.isdir(s):
                shutil.copytree(s, d_test, symlinks, ignore)
                print "Copytree used! - TEST"
            else:
                shutil.copy2(s, d_test)
                print "Copy 2 used! - TEST"

copytree(src_abs,destination_data_abs,True)
```

the code is being executed on a unix machine ... if that matters?

Comment: Because you're doing it randomly, if you did it many, many times, you would get a distribution with a perfect 50/50 split in the center, but not every run will be a 50/50 split. I'd suggest generating a list of 1s and 0s that is the length of the amount of files you have, with the proportion of 1s and 0s determined by your `split`, then randomize the list order.
edit: @user6770522's answer has a better implementation of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the list of files, **shuffle** it, then **split** it with respect to the split ratio.

```
import os
import numpy

src_files = os.listdir(".")
n_files = len(src_files)

split_ratio = 0.5
split_index = int(n_files * split_ratio)

numpy.random.shuffle(src_files)

print src_files[0:split_index]
print src_files[split_index:]
```

[Flipping a coin 84 times will result in a "perfect" 42 heads / 42 tails with a probability of 0.0868.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=flip%2084%20coins)

Comment: Thanks just what i needed :)